# Names for parts of a polynomial

Tags: calculus, polynomials, notation

I have the following polynomial: $a+bx^3+cx^5+dx^7$

I know that $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are the coefficients.

What is the correct name for $x^3$, $x^5$, and $x^7$? 
That is, what are these variables called?

Comment: @NormalHuman, fixed

Comment: I have heard these referred to as *the powers of the independent variable* (or *variables* in the case of a multivariate polynomial). I can't give a reference though.

Comment: Some authors call $x^\alpha$ a *monomial* (also for multivariate polynomials, and including the "hidden" $x^0$ for the trailing coefficient), and $c x^\alpha$ a *term* of the polynomial. Other authors use *monomial* just as I described *term*, that is, they include the coefficient in the monomial; in that case, I second Antonio's comment to call the $x^\alpha$ *powers of the variable(s)*.

Also from my side, no reference, unless you allow me to cite myself as an example of authors of the first kind... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any other way of explaining this other than $x^3$, $x^5$, and $x^7$ are your variables all raised to odd powers (different degrees).

So their names are *polynomial variables*.

Since the highest degree is $7$ you have a 'Septic' polynomial.

[This](https://web.archive.org/web/20171223103746/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/56413.html) is an answer for a similar question to yours.

Comment: To be clear: the polynomial (ring)'s variable is just $x$, without any exponent - the $x^3$ etc. are its powers. Since the question is about correct notation, I guess we should be picky here...

Comment: @akobel, thanks, I unmarked this as the correct answer